# FullCalendar eventClick from outside working with problems

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Hi I have this current JS for fullCalendar (v 1.6.4):

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    element.find('.fc-event-inner').attr("id", "event-" + event.id_event);
},
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    alert("Event clicked: "+calEvent);
}
```

This works ok if I click on an event.

I than have this button:

```
$('#ext-click').click(function(){
    $('#event-120.fc-event-inner').trigger('click');
})
```

(Note: `#event-120` is a correct id for the event)

Now, when clicking on `#ext-event` button nothing happens, BUT, if I click on the `event-120` I get the alert, I close the alert and I press `#ext-event` this time the alert appears.

So `#ext-event` works only if I first click on `event-120`, otherwise nothing happens.

**Expectancy:**
When clicking on `#ext-event` I should get the `event-120` alert every time.

Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hs0q6r3v/1/

You will see by clicking the "Click-me" button as first thing, nothing happens. Click then on the event, you'll get an alert, close it and click on the "Click-me" button again, this time it works.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Done, please see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hs0q6r3v/1/

Comment: I changed it here https://jsfiddle.net/WhitecastlePT/p7g8fn34/

I added the click event when the event was rendered.

Comment: I'm sorry but i did not understood your question can you refrase please.

Comment: @HenriqueC. Is there a way to pass in your click event, all of the event data? So that all the event data are accessible in the click event? (like they would in the eventClick standard method)

Comment: i have updated the jsfiddle. Yes you can access all of the event data. Check in chrome your console log while in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to rethink this user experience approach by triggering a click by button. What's the reason for that? If you want to do a select then use the fullcalendar select method, etc.

**Why it's probably not working:**
A fullcalendar event is different from a  with the id of a fullcalendar id. That might be the reason why the order of clicking is important cause there is a listener generated for this div showing this event. But you can't rely on that the internal Id of an event will always be reflected in the DOM.
e.g. In the latest fullcalendar release the fullcalendar event_id is not used for the id of the related

**Approaches for dealing with page change:**
I use both approaches in my applications

1. New Page

   - calendarview has optional parameter
   - pass  "selected_id" to the new page
   - when leaving "new_page" pass back "selected_id"
   - when calendarview receives a "selected_id"  deal with it in the "eventRender" method (e.g. special styling for highlighting, ...)
2. Modal Dialog 
   if convenient you can also use a modal dialog, so the calendarview will stay the same.

Comment: Perhaps this can be done in another way. The reason I want to trigger an event click is that my app at one point changes page entirely, but I keep the event id in the "bullpen" and once I'm back to that page I make it trigger-click. Any better idea for it?

Comment: I do use a modal but that's on eventClick anyways, so we are back to the same issue

Comment: why you don't implement your own "doEventClick(...)" inside your "eventClick" which is also called when coming back to your calendarview with a previously selected event_id?